# How do I generate a signature for a settle request in Amazon FPS Marketplace?

Tags: signature, frame-rate, marketplace

The documentation is really awful, and while creating a button to reserve a credit card payment is fairly straightforward, being able to release that payment is a pain. I'm having most trouble with actually generating that signature.

Anyone use FPS before and have an idea?

Thanks!